# Search multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, search

I have a table structured like this (not the actual data or fields, but the same structure applies):

```
ID | City        Field2 Field 3
-------------------------------
1    New York    Ohio   data      
2    Cincinnati  data   data
3    Los Angeles data   Ohio
4    Cleveland   data   data
```

Then there's a second table something like this (again, not the actual data)

```
City        State
-------------------------------
Los Angeles California
New York    New York
Cincinnati  Ohio
Cleveland   Ohio
Houston     Texas
```

etc.

I have a php web page that allows users to search the database; when they do, it will automatically print (in my example) the corresponding state from the second table after the city.

However, if the user searches for "Ohio", it should return all four records, even though "Ohio" doesn't exist in the first table. It looks like I'd have to run multiple queries - find the search term in the first table, find it again in the second table, and then search for column 1 of the second table in the first table (and then join the results). Is there an easier way to do that? (I'm fairly new to MySQL.)

Comment: You could make a reference table or UNION the results of multiple queries into one.  You could even do a full-text type search.

Comment: can you show your php web page's code?

Comment: I really don't get it... if someone searches for "Ohio" you want to return "New York", "Los Angeles", "Cincinnati" and "Cleveland", and that's fine. But if someone searches for "New York" you need to return "New York"? and "Cleveland"... you need to return "Ohio"? And what about "Houston"?

Comment: Like I said - not the actual data, which isn't city/state. Essentially, I want the search to return all rows which contain the search term, which can occur in multiple fields. Except some of the information which will contain the search term is in a separate table - in this example, every time "Cincinnati" appears, I'd have to include "Ohio" along with several more columns, some of which may change data later. I need it to return the entire row - in the example, "Ohio" returns the "New York" row because "Ohio" is in field 2. Not sure UNION would work since I need the whole row.

Comment: Not sure what a reference table is - do you have a link to explain that? The query I currently use is on one table (which varies depending on what the user is searching for): SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE 'field 2' LIKE %{$searchterm}% OR 'field 3' LIKE %{$searchterm}%, and then I process the row and display the data for each row returned.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a `UNION`?

```
SELECT City FROM table1 WHERE Field2 = 'Ohio' OR Field3 = 'Ohio'
UNION ALL
SELECT City FROM table2 WHERE State = 'Ohio'
```

It would be helpful to see what your query looks like.